# Continually send message from background.js to popup.js in setInterval but only when popup is opened?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, setinterval

I am a beginner. I am trying to write a simple extension. The idea is running a countdown timer in background.js and display it in the popup.html. I write some code below.

**background.js**

```
function countdown() {
    window.intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        window.remaining_time -= 1000;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(get_status()), function(response) {
            console.log("Respond receive!");
        })
    }, 1000)
}
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("message received: " + msg);
        if (msg == "Background port started!") {
            return;
        }
        let timer_status = JSON.parse(msg);
        let remaining_time = timer_status.remaining_time;
        let curr_mode = timer_status.curr_mode;
        let timer_state = timer_status.timer_state;

        var days = Math.floor(remaining_time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((remaining_time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var mins = Math.floor((remaining_time % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var secs = Math.floor((remaining_time % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        var countdown_str = "";
        if (days > 0) {
            countdown_str += days + " days ";
        }
        if (hours > 0) {
            countdown_str += hours + " hours ";
        }
        if (mins > 0) {
            countdown_str += mins + " mins ";
        }
        countdown_str += secs + " secs";
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = countdown_str;
        sendResponse({farewell:"Goodbye"});
    }
)
```

The code running fine when the popup is open. However, when the popup is closed, the problem occured as "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist".

I've looked for popup closing event but it seems not to exist. So my question is are there any **ELEGANT** way to continually send messages from background.js to popup.js in setInterval but only when the popup script is opened?

Comment: The popup runs only when shown, it's just like any other page, so you need to reverse the direction of communication - the popup should initiate it, the background script should listen. Also there's no need for JSON.

Comment: @wOxxOm In this situation, the countdown timer is running on the background.js side, so I think it would be more suitable if we send messages from the background.js. I have thought about sending a message from popup.js every second to request for status in background.js but that is a little bit clumsy for me. So I'm looking for an **ELEGANT** way to do this as I emphasized in the question.

Comment: "Elegant" is subjective and thus not really suitable for a question on a technical resource. From my point of view the elegant way is the technically correct way: the popup should initiate the communication. It doesn't have to send a message every second, it can do it one time when it starts. Depending on how that counter is used there could be dozens of solutions.

Comment: Also note, insisting on emotional/opinionated solutions makes the question a candidate to close as "primarily opinion-based" as explained in the rules: many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Back to technical angle, directly accessing chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().remaining_time in the popup instead of messaging can be also a solution provided your background script is declared with persistent:true.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your feedback. Also directly accessing using background page is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the popup is not open this will fail and abort the execution of the sendresponse

```
     document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = countdown_str;
     sendResponse({farewell:"Goodbye"});
```

either use try

```
    try{
         var test=   document.getElementById("countdown");
         if(test){ test.innerHTML= countdown_str;}

         }catch (ex){
             console.log(ex);
             console.log(typeof(test)); //also a possible way to check
     }
```

or check it something like this

```
           if(document.body.contains(document.getElementById('test'))){
              alert('Element exists!');
           } else{
              alert('Element does not exist!');
           }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it looks like you misunderstood my question.